# Keep currently calculated values when flattening pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, visual-studio-2017

I'm using itextsharp 5.5 to set the field values of several non-calculated fields in a pdf. The pdf also contains calculated values. What I'd like to do is to have the calculated values be calculated, then make all the fields read-only so that users that open the pdf can't edit the values anymore.

I have managed to get the calculated values using

```
pdfStamper.JavaScript = "this.calculateNow();";
```

but this leaves the fields editable. Using

```
pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
```

makes the fields read-only, but the calculated values are removed again. Even if I only calculate, save the pdf as a temporary file, open the temporary file and save it again with FormFlattening set to true, the final pdf doesn't have the calculated values anymore.

Interestingly, if I set FormFlattening to false and don't include the line `pdfReader.RemoveUsageRights();`

the resulting pdf gives the error "This document enabled extended features in Adobe Reader. The document has been changed since it was created and use of extended features is no longer available" when opened in Adobe Reader, but after closing that error message the pdf looks ok, the calculated fields are filled and the document is read-only as desired. But as the resulting pdfs are to be distributed, having them all throw up error messages is not a solution.

So my question is, is there any way to use FormFlattening while keeping whatever the currently calculated values of fields are? Is there another way to make the fields read-only? Is the behavior when I don't include RemoveUsageRights something I can use, or are the fields only not editable because of the error?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by setting all the fields in the PDF to Read Only using

```
foreach (var key in pdfFormFields.Fields.Keys){
  pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty(key, "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
}
```

This keeps the calculated values while preventing further edits. But it's not very neat, and Adobe Reader somehow always considers the file dirty and will prompt a save dialogue when trying to close Reader with the PDF open. So I'm still open for better ideas (or a fix for the save-prompting with this solution).